# adding 2 object arrays in C#

Tags: c#

I have 2 arrays of objects and I want to add one to the other. This seems simple enough but nothing seems to work. Here is what I am trying now.

```
Module[] StaticModules;
Module[] DynamicModules;

Info = Database.Devices[inx];
//Modules = Database.GetDeviceModules(Info);

StaticModules = Database.GetDeviceModules(Info);
DynamicModules = Database.GetDeviceModules(new int[] { 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 });

Array.Resize(ref StaticModules, StaticModules.Length + DynamicModules.Length);
Array.Copy(StaticModules, DynamicModules, DynamicModules.Length);

Modules = StaticModules;
```

Everything seems ok until the copy which seems to take forever and doesn't appear to do a thing. At one point I had the watch window open and after the copy all my vars turned red and I saw a message that said I had to refresh because the last function timed out.

Comment: the first parameter to Copy should be the source, your resize call suggests you think it is the destination.

Comment: You are trying to copy the `DynamicModules` values into `StaticModules`, is that correct?

Comment: Do you _have_ to use arrays or can use more dynamic structures like `List`?

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems overly complicated. Why not do:

```
Modules = StaticModules.Concat(DynamicModules).ToArray();
```

Comment: I tried the concat route but I couldn't get that to work either. I'll try what you suggest here. I think i was doing Modules.Concat(DynamicModules) and not seeing any change.

Answer (score 1):

Array.Copy method has several overloads. You might need to use this one [Array.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft(v=vs.110).aspx). The overload you chose overwrites elements of the destination array as they pastes items starting form index 0. Also as @muratgu said first argument is the source array.

```
Module[] StaticModules;
    Module[] DynamicModules;

    Info = Database.Devices[inx];
    //Modules = Database.GetDeviceModules(Info);

    StaticModules = Database.GetDeviceModules(Info);
    var len = StaticModules.Length;

    DynamicModules = Database.GetDeviceModules(new int[] { 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 });



    Array.Resize(ref StaticModules, StaticModules.Length + DynamicModules.Length);
    Array.Copy(DynamicModules, 0, StaticModules, len, DynamicModules.Length);

    Modules = StaticModules;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CopyTo for this.

```
Module[] StaticModules;
Module[] DynamicModules;
Module[] FinalModules = new Module[StaticModules.Length + DynamicModules.Length];

StaticModules.CopyTo(FinalModules, 0);
DynamicModules.CopyTo(FinalModules, StaticModules.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. I tried it in a compiler to see the results.

```
Array.Copy(DynamicModules, 0, StaticModules, DynamicModules.Length, DynamicModules.Length);
```

Full code:

```
Module[] StaticModules;
Module[] DynamicModules;

Info = Database.Devices[inx];
//Modules = Database.GetDeviceModules(Info);

StaticModules = Database.GetDeviceModules(Info);
DynamicModules = Database.GetDeviceModules(new int[] { 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 });

Array.Resize(ref StaticModules, StaticModules.Length + DynamicModules.Length);
Array.Copy(DynamicModules, 0, StaticModules, DynamicModules.Length, DynamicModules.Length);

Modules = StaticModules;
```